# Firebase deployment only showing background gray color, no errors I suspect it has somthing to do with MUITheme

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-functions, redux-thunk

UPDATE!!!
Ok I have fixed all issues, they just needed (foo) to be added to them and for MyButton.js it just needed to be a variable and then exported, HOWEVER I still have this gray background when i create it as a static server, or try to serve it on firebase?! this is what I see.
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I suspect it is either express or MUITheme from material-ui its also worth noting that if I click the deployed firebase link it opens automatically in my chrome that has react developer tools and redux devtools connected to the site and runs perfectly fine. Below is my App.js code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { unstable_createMuiStrictModeTheme as createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import themeFile from './util/theme';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { SET_AUTHENTICATED } from './redux/types';
import { logoutUser, getUserData } from './redux/actions/userActions';
// Components
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import AuthRoute from './util/AuthRoute';
// import themeObject from './util/theme';
// Pages
import home from './pages/home';
import login from './pages/login';
import signup from './pages/signup';
import user from './pages/user';
import axios from 'axios';

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeFile);

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://NOT SHOWING YOU THIS BUT TRUST ME ITS CORRECT.cloudfunctions.net/api";

const token = localStorage.FBIdToken;
if(token){
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()){
    store.dispatch(logoutUser())
    window.location.href = '/login';
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_AUTHENTICATED });
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    store.dispatch(getUserData());

  }
}

 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

      
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Navbar />
          <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={home}/>
            <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={login} />
            <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={signup} />
            <Route exact path="/users/:handle" component={user} />
            <Route exact path="/users/:handle/scream/:screamId" component={user} />
          </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
        </Provider>
        
      
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please, don't post text as images.

Comment: Ok Ill place the code in their place

Comment: How is your build and deploy process?

Comment: firebase init 
Are you ready to proceed? (Y/n) y
Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
What do you want to use as your public directory? build
Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N) y
Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? (y/N) n
File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) y
Then npm run build or Yarn build (I have tried both now) 
Then firebase deploy, and it deploys and loads the viacom image and the grey background but nothing else, I suspect its material-ui (MUITheme) thats the issue.

Comment: I just deleted node_modules and package-lock.json then in terminal: yarn so yarn installing everything also noticed in dependencies "@material-ui/styles" was not in there so I added it, fingers crossed this fixes the issue.

Comment: also here is the deployed link and i am receiving this when i inspect in internet explorer not sure if it matters.in the body.
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

https://stfu-9a779.web.app/

Comment: I can see a working web there with some photos, a Home/Login/SignUp menu, etc. I can also access the full React components tree using the ReactDevTools.